# codeigniter autocomplete send data

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, autocomplete

im using jquery.autocomplete.js to made autocomplete on my project. I already success to make it, but i cant get the data i need from that autocomplete.

Controller

```
foreach($data->result() as $row)
    {
        $arr['query'] = $keyword;
        $arr['suggestions'][] = array(
            'data' => $row->nim,
            'value' => $row->nim." - ".$row->nama
        );
    }
```

That is my controller for taking suggestion data, it will result [Nim] - [Nama] since i set the value like that, but when i get the data from the input i cant get [Nim] only rather than [Nim] - [Nama]. So, how could i get [Nim] from my input without delete [Nama]?

var_dump result

```
string(24) "71120001 - Pedro Nadirio"
```

view

```
<div class="panel-body col-lg-10">
     <div class="list-group">
     <form action="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/asisten/tambahAsistenAction/<?php echo $idKelas ?>" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-2">Nama / NIM Mahasiswa</label>
              <div class="col-sm-7">
                   <input id="asisten" type="search" class="form-control" name="asisten">
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-2"></label>
              <div class="col-sm-7">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Simpan</button>
              </div>
          </div>
     </form>
     </div>
```

And this is the script for autocomplete

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function(){
      $("#asisten").autocomplete({
        serviceUrl: '<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/asisten/search'
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: var_dump($data) and please show us your view

Comment: edited for var_dump and view